# How to convert ticks into a readable datetime with XSLT?

Tags: datetime, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML with timestamps like this:

```
<node stamp="1236888746689" />
```

And I would like to display them in the result HTML as date with time.
Is there a way to do it with XSLT (any Version)?

**EDIT:** 
I am using XSLT2.0 with Saxon9. The base date is 1970-01-01 0:00.

Comment: Technically possible, but inefficient and requiring further input (like a definition of zero-time). I would batch this out to an extension - what's your platform?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You take the date `1970-01-01T00:00:00` and add as many milliseconds as the value of the stamp tells you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <xsl:value-of
select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + @stamp * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How would one modify the answer to use the inner text in a node, instead of an attribute on it?

Comment: @Broam Wrap the `<xsl:value-of` with a `<xsl:attribute name="MyAttribute"></xsl:attribute>`.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor which supports the [EXSLT date functions](http://exslt.org/date/index.html) (I've just tested this with [libxslt](http://www.xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) in PHP), you can use [`date:add()`](http://exslt.org/date/functions/add/index.html) and [`date:duration()`](http://exslt.org/date/functions/duration/index.html):

```
<xsl:value-of select="date:add('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', date:duration(@stamp div 1000))"/>
```

The `date:duration()` function takes a number of seconds (so you have to divide your milliseconds by 1000) and turns it into a "duration" (in this case, "`P14315DT20H12M26.6889998912811S`"), which is then added to the start of your epoch (looks like the standard epoch, for this stamp) with `date:add()` to get a stamp of "`2009-03-12T20:12:26.6889998912811Z`".  You can then format this using the EXSLT date functions or just [`substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath.html#function-substring), depending on what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Belated answer, yes, I know, but I couldn't find the one I was looking for here, so I thought I'd pay it forward with my solution.

My XML was a few nodes dumped from Drupal using export_node and drush. I was using the xslt processor in PHP5, which only supports xslt 1.0. Some EXSLT functions appear to be supported, but I couldn't tell whether my syntax was wrong or the function I was trying to use was not supported. Anyway, the following worked for me. I used the example code from w3schools.com, but added a line right after declaring the xsltprocessor, like below:

$xp = new XsltProcessor();
$xp->registerPHPFunctions();

PHP has a trivial function for date conversion, so I cheated and used the PHP processor, since I was already using it to transform my xsl.

```
<xsl:for-each select="node_export/node">
  <xsl:value-of select="php:function('date', 'n-j-y', number(timestamp))"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Hope this helps someone out there. I was banging my head for quite a while as I worked this one out.

Comment: I also found I needed to use this: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
    xsl:extension-element-prefixes="php">`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use an XSL 1.0 processor that does not support the [EXSLT date and time functions](http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html) this is non-trivial, but it has been done.

You can have a look at [Katy Coe's XSLT 1.0 implementation of the "iso-from-unix" function](http://www.djkaty.com/xsl-date-time). It's part of a rather huge "free for non-commercial use" set of date and time functions she created.

However, your XSL processor must support the [`"http://exslt.org/functions"`](http://www.exslt.org/func/index.html) namespace for this implementation to work. Other than that there is no dependency on EXSLT.

P.S.: I'm aware that a Unix timestamp and ticks are not *exactly* the same thing. They are close enough, though.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_complete), so there must be a way. :) Knowing at least a bit of XSLT, it will probably involve recursion.

You don't specify the exact interpretation of your "ticks", I'm guessing milliseconds since some epoch, but which? 1970?